# Parse.com SDK v1.2.20 won't compile for ARM64bit architecture

Tags: ios, parse-platform, arm64

I followed the quick start tutorial and solved issues with the Facebook SDK being required (Even though I'm not using Facebook), but for some reason even though I'm using a version of the Parse SDK that should be compatible for 64bit architectures I am receiving errors stating that it can't compile for my iPhone 5S's 64bit architecture...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The code it crashes on is when I just set up the Parse object and analytics:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"MyAppID"
                  clientKey:@"MyClientID"];
    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    return YES;
}
```

My `Other Linker Flags` includes `-ObjC` and my `Standard Architectures` & `Valid Architectures` both include `arm64`, `armv7s`, & `armv7`

Comment: There must be something else misconfigured... Can you try an empty project without `-ObjC` and without Facebook?

Comment: It works perfectly in an empty project without the `-ObjC` and Facebook SDK...If I remove the `-ObjC` flag from my app it compiles, but then the CorePlot framework crashes when called bc it requires the `-ObjC` flag

Comment: Try using the -force_load flag to load CorePlot/deps without requiring the -ObjC

Comment: Thank You @Fosco. That worked perfectly. No more errors and everything seems to be working fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove the `-ObjC` linker flag and the Facebook SDK. This lead to an error with another 3rd party framework I was using which required the `-ObjC` linker flag, but @Fosco suggested I force load the framework I needed using the `-force_load path/to/framework` flag which solved all my problems.

Answer (score 1):

You did not imported all the frameworks that is needed to use the Parse SDK.

**AudioToolbox.framework

CFNetwork.framework

CoreGraphics.framework

CoreLocation.framework

libz.dylib

MobileCoreServices.framework

QuartzCore.framework

Security.framework

StoreKit.framework

SystemConfiguration.framework**

And you need to make sure that you market the COPY option when moved the PARSE SDK into your framework

Comment: I have all those frameworks imported, as that was one of the steps with the quick start tutorial, and I just deleted and re-imported the Parse SDK making sure that COPY was selected and still nothing different happened..

Comment: I started using PARSE yesterday and I also use the FACEBOOK SDK and everything works normally. The only different thing in mine app is that I put [FBLoginView Class] and [FBProfilePictureView Class] in the didFinishLaunching in the APPDelegate so I don`t need to flag the "-objc" .

Comment: adding the MobileCoreServices.framework fixed this for me

Answer (score 0):

Adding Bolts.framework that comes with Parse frameworks to the project solved the problem for me. Hope this helps